# Run Custom Movenet Model on tfjs demo

Tags: frontend, client-side, tensorflow.js, movenet

I have compiled a new tfjs odel with a model.json file containing the model information and a bin file containing the weights and I want to try running my custom model on the tfjs model demo.
Link here: https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/pose-detection/index.html?model=movenet

There is an option for custom model, however I am not able to run it as it keeps giving me errors. How can I run my model here. The use case for me is to be able to take the video feed from the user and display my model and then compare the specific poses with my model.

I already tried this using javascript and I do not know how I can make the model work in front end camera taken from the user.
I heard there is a way we can do this with angular and if so what is a possible approach